# worried about prior marijuana use

Tags: parents, communication

If I used marijuana everyday before I found out I was pregnant ( I quit as soon as I found out) My question is when my blood work comes back from first doctors appointment positive for THC , will CPS get involved? Does anyone know.

Comment: Why would it be tested for THC?

Comment: @rhialto I got drug tested 3 times during my pregnancy, even though there was no particular indication for the tests.  I was told it is standard practice.

Comment: @Meg I’m surprised irrelevant blood tests are being done without consent. Maybe you have a local law that mandates it? In the UK this would be illegal and put a doctor or midwife’s registration in doubt. OP - whether CPS (I presume that’s your local social services) gets involved in response to a drug test is going to depend on local law.

Comment: I'm guessing this is in the U.S. (due to CPS being the relevant agency), but I think it will need a more specific location to be answerable. Laws and situations can vary a lot between states, and it's state policy that's going to matter on this. Also potentially relevant, depending on which state you're in: are you currently drawing any public benefits, especially any related (but not limited to) medical care during your pregnancy?

Comment: Regardless of details, this seems like a legal question, which isn't on topic for this site.  Please see the [faq] and the [help] for more information about what's on topic here.  Thanks!